# Android NavGraph android:label"sample tile" not working

Tags: android, android-architecture-components, android-jetpack-navigation

I am working on adding a toolbar title in the NavGraph. I used `android:label"sample tile"` in the NavGraph, but its not updating the toolbar with the label.

Tried using `android:label` in the NavGraph, but its not updating the title of the toolbar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `android:label` alone won't be fully integrated with jetpack navigation.

[In documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-ui#top_app_bar):

> NavigationUI contains methods that automatically update content in
> your top app bar as users navigate through your app. For example,
> NavigationUI uses the destination labels from your navigation graph to
> keep the title of the top app bar up-to-date.

So, you need to configure the top app bar to work with `NavigationUI` and this is done through [`setupWithNavController()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/navigation/ui/NavigationUI#setupWithNavController(android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar,%20androidx.navigation.NavController,%20androidx.navigation.ui.AppBarConfiguration)).

[This section](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-ui#create_a_toolbar) in documentations provides an example:

```
// Kotlin
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    ...

    val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment)
    val appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(navController.graph)
    findViewById<Toolbar>(R.id.toolbar)
        .setupWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration)
}

// Java
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ...

    NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
    AppBarConfiguration appBarConfiguration =
            new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(navController.getGraph()).build();
    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(
            toolbar, navController, appBarConfiguration);
}
```

Comment: Hey Zain,
Thanks for responding to the post. Can I know what does nav_host_fragment represents in this code?

Comment: @JeffySajan Please check the doc here https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/navigation/fragment/NavHostFragment